# Golang lib/pg can't connect to postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

I have such code:

```
package main

import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "log"

        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=vagrant sslmode=disable")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT 3+5")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(rows)
}
```

And its result is:

```
[vagrant@localhost go-postgres]$ go run test.go
2015/12/19 11:03:53 pq: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
exit status 1
```

But I can access postgres:

```
[vagrant@localhost go-postgres]$ psql -U postgres vagrant
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

vagrant=#
```

And I don't have any troubles with using Rails app with postgres.

Anyone has an idea?

EDIT:
Here is my pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

EDIT2:

I found this in my postgres logs:

```
< 2015-12-19 12:13:05.094 UTC >LOG:  could not connect to Ident server at address "::1", port 113: Connection refused
< 2015-12-19 12:13:05.094 UTC >FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
< 2015-12-19 12:13:05.094 UTC >DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 84: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident"
```

I think it will really help ;)

Comment: Are you sure the user postgres has no password? I.e. does `user=postgres password=postgres` work?

Comment: @Ainar-G I am. I can connect to psql and use other app (Rails) without password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok,
correct connection string is:

```
"user=postgres host=/tmp dbname=vagrant sslmode=disable"
```

I assumed pg library uses same defaults as `psql` or ruby driver. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

Run in console:

```
psql "user=postgres dbname=vagrant sslmode=disable"
```

If you cannot connect so it needs to change sslmode else I will think more.

Comment: show please "cat /var/lib/pgsql/<your version>/data/pg_hba.conf" results

Comment: try to replace "ident" into "trust"

Comment: I have on my server:
local   all             all                                     trust;
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust;
host    all             all             ::1/128                trust

Comment: Ok, looks like I am lazy... I needed to check this option: `host - The host to connect to. Values that start with / are for unix domain sockets. (default is localhost)`. Other drivers by default use unix socket, here default is localhost. And looks like I don't have ident installed...

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting host to */run/postgresql* worked.
Credit: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/645#issuecomment-320799610

The host url depends on the socket Postgres is using. [The socket location varies based on how and where postgres was built](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21044.1326496507@sss.pgh.pa.us). The socket location can be found using:

- Inside psql, run `\conninfo`. It shows the socket location along with other details
- `unix_socket_directory` value in postgresql.conf

In my Ubuntu distro, */var/run* is a soft link to */run*, that's why */run/postgresql* works even though `unix_socket_directory` and `\conninfo` mention */var/run/postgresql*.